# Binding GlobalStateStore into Processor with spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Initial Question:
I have a question how I can bind my GlobalStateStore to a processor. My Application has a GlobalStateStore with an own processor ("GlobalConfigProcessor") to keep the Store up to date. Also, I have another Processor ("MyClassProcessor") which is called in my Consumer Function. Now I try to access the store from MyClassProcessor, but I get an exception saying : Invalid topology: StateStore config_statestore is not added yet.

Update on current situation:
I setup a test repository to give a better overview over my situation. This can be found here: https://github.com/fx42/store-example

As you can see in the repo, I have two Consumers which both consume different topics. The Config-Topic provides an event which I want to write to a GlobalStateStore. Here are the StateStoreUpdateConsumer.java and the StateStoreProcessor.java involved.
With the MyClassEventConsumer.java I process another Input-Topic and want to read values from the GlobalStateStore.
As provided in this [doc](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/kafka-streams.adoc#streamsbuilderfactorybean-customizer) I can't initialize GlobalStateStores just as StateStoreBean but instead I have to add this actively with the StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer Bean. This Code is currently commented out in the StreamConfig.java. Without this code I get the Exception

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.
```

If the code is in use I get the exception:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to initialize state, this can happen if multiple instances of Kafka Streams are running in the same state directory
```

So this leads my to the decision, that I have a configuration problem so the topology is messed up.

Questions:

1. When I provide the Processor for the GlobalStateStore directly via

```
streamBuilder.addGlobalStore(storeBuilder, configInputTopic,
                            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()), () -> new StateStoreProcessor(statestoreName));
```

do I have to provide a Consumer Function for this Processor or do I even have to mention it in the function configuration/application.yml?

2. Is there a way NOT to provide a ProcessorSupplier into the `addGlobalStore` call and just use the functional way for this?
3. How can I handle this GlobalStateStore if there are two different topologies for both the defined functions?

Here is the commented out StreamBuilderFactoryCustomizer Bean which I use to add the GlobalStateStore to the FactoryBean:

```
@Bean
StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer(
            StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> storeBuilder) {

        return factoryBean -> {
            try {
                var streamBuilder = factoryBean.getObject();
                streamBuilder.addGlobalStore(storeBuilder, configInputTopic,
                        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()), () -> new StateStoreProcessor(statestoreName));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    } };
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue is. Maybe you want to create a small reproducible sample? From a quick look, it seems like you are attaching the state store to a processor called `GlobalConfigProcessor` while trying to access the same store from another processor called `MyClassProcessor`. It is not obvious to determine whether that is the issue, but that could be something that you can start looking.

Comment: You are right. That the exact thing I want to do. When I add a GlobalStateStore it is recommended to add a specific Processor to keep the store up to data, aka. putting new values into the store. Also the documentation says that ever processor has a read access to every GlobalStateStore by default. So from my understanding having two processors is the right way to interact with the GlobalStateStore, one for putting new entries and one for reading it.

Comment: Here is the doc I was refering to: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/latest/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#addGlobalStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier-

Comment: Feel free to create a very minimal sample where the issue can be re-produced, then we can triage further.

Comment: I updated the question and provided a test repo with a similar setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. For me it was the @EnableKafkaStreams annotation which I used. I assume this was the reason I had two different contexts running in parallel and they collided. Also I needed to use the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer` instead of `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer` to get the GlobalStateStore registered correctly.
Theses changes done in the linked test-repo which now can start the Application Context properly.

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured this out. I was going to take a look at your app later today.